# Trying to find the name of a gear system

Tags: mechanical-engineering, gears

I am trying to figure out the name of a gear type, I think it is a scissor gear, however when looking it up I dont find anything by that name. The gear is simple with a center screw and two nuts. The nuts have links attached to them that then attach to a ring. When the center screw is rotated clockwise the bottom nut is screwed down while the top nut goes up, the system as a whole pulls in (blue). When the center screw is rotated counter-clockwise the bottom nut is screwed up and the top nut is screwed down, the system as a whole pushed up (red). The photo below shows a photo example.

I am curious about the name so I can look more into the gear, and possible alternatives that can withstand bending if one side is pushed (green).
[image]

Comment: The scissor lift can be accomplished with a single right hand screw and nut. The bolt head end is fixed to allow rotation, but to prevent advancement in either direction on one end and the nut being driven at the other end travels along the screw thereby driving the lift action. More complex would be left hand on one end and right hand on the other with left and right threaded nuts. Another embodiment is the turnbuckle where only the screws advance relative to the frame. The turnbuckle could replace your need for "scissors" alltogether.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Scissor Jack Lift** is the correct term and is used in the vertical mode to lift cars.

You would have to brace it in other ways to prevent lateral forces of the green arrow.

This one has a swivel top.

[image]

This is an old Audi jack.

Auto wreckers should have many of these.
[image]

This is an old BMW jack.
Newer ones are single-sided with worm gear & handle in motion axis.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure you have the threaded rod drawn correctly.

Usually designs like that have a left and right hand thread on the threaded rod so the nuts get drawn together or pushed apart, which controls the spreading (red arrows) or tension (blue arrows).

Comment: After reviewing the system you are right, the top should move as well. I take it you dont know the official name of the system though?